# Does appscript require G-Docs enabled, even for the basic app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I was trying to run this app from an account that has disabled Google Docs.

```js
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(button);

  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.')
                .setId('statusLabel')
                .setVisible(false);
  app.add(label);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  handler.addCallbackElement(label);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setVisible(true);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

I was unable to run this code, it doesn't require/use Google Docs permission (confirm in OAuth scree), but I'm still getting an error that says:

> "We are sorry, but you do not have access to Google Spreadsheets.
>   Please contact your domain administrator for access."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, as this is not really about spreadsheets. But you'll not be able to run an Apps Script web app (as the user) on an Apps account with Google Drive/Docs disabled. Apps Script is part of Google Drive, and by disabling it you disable Apps Script as well.

I don't think the Apps Script team ever thought they would have so much use outside of Google Drive environment. I guess you could open an enhancement request on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), I feel this is something they'd consider. Please remember to describe the use-cases you have in mind for this. But don't get your hopes up, this is very likely **not** going to change on the near future.